# Building Cocoa UIs for OS X with C# and Mono

Tags: c#, cocoa, macos, mono

Has anyone spent any time comparing the various Objective C bridges and associated Cocoa wrappers for Mono?

I want to port an existing C# application to run on OS X. Ideally I'd run the application on Mono, and build a native Cocoa UI for it.

I'm wondering which bridge would be the best choice.

In case it's useful to anyone, here are some links to bridges I've found so far:

- **CocoSharp** - distributed with Mono on OS X - [www.cocoa-sharp.com](http://www.cocoa-sharp.com)
- **Monobjc** - better documentation than the others (in my opinion) - [www.mono-project.com/CocoaSharp](http://www.mono-project.com/CocoaSharp) and [www.monobjc.net](http://www.monobjc.net)
- **NObjective** - (apparently) faster than the others - [code.google.com/p/nobjective](http://code.google.com/p/nobjective)
- **MObjc / MCocoa** - [code.google.com/p/mobjc](http://code.google.com/p/mobjc) and [code.google.com/p/mcocoa](http://code.google.com/p/mcocoa)
- **ObjC#** - [www.mono-project.com/ObjCSharp](http://www.mono-project.com/ObjCSharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mono team have released a new bridge called MonoMac.

It's essentially the desktop version of the MonoTouch framework they produced for the iPhone.

Miguel announced the new bridge on his blog here: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Apr-19.html

Once MonoMac matures, I suspect that it will become *the* bridge people use.

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying out Monobjc, NObjective and MObjc/MCocoa with F# lately and I will go with MObjc/MCocoa.

Monobjc is as you write best documented and packaged but compared to the other two very [slow](http://code.google.com/p/nobjective/) and does not "rethrow exceptions" from ObjC.

I believe that NObjective and MObjc/MCocoa are the only two that rethrow exceptions from ObjC and that's why I find them to be the only real alternatives.

As discussed [here](http://www.nabble.com/NObjective-and-Inheritance-td21882576ef1367.html) NObjective uses structs with inheritance which I find quite scary and made me finally choose MObjC/MCocoa.

(You might have a licence issue as well. Monobjc and NObjective is under LGPL, MObjc/MCocoa is under MIT ...)

Comment: Johan I removed the accepted answer flag from your answer. Please don't be offended by this. Your answer is still valuable, but I feel that MonoMac is the way forward. I wanted this page to reflect that.

Comment: No offense taken... :) I also believe that the release of MacMono has changed the situation...

Answer (score 1):

I think that NObjective is the best choise coz it have automatic code generation for Objective-C wrappers that can be easily configured to regenerate wrappers for further versions of Mac OS.

Comment: Any comments on what you've used it for, or problems you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll ask: why would you want to do this? Cocoa's UI archtecture, including Cocoa-std delgates and Cocoa bindngs are closely tied to Objective-C. The combination of Interface Builder and Objective-C is remarkably productive. Although you can use Interface Builder with many bridges to Objective-C (including PyObjC, MacRuby, and many of the C# bridges), you will inevitably loose productivity due to any impedance mismatch between the framework and your language of choice. With C#, this mismatch is significant. Since you're writing a native UI, thus loosing any cross-platform advantage you would gain from C#, I would use Objective-C. For a competent C/C++/C#/Java/etc. programmer, it generally takes 2-3 days to become comfortable and productive in Objective-C.

Comment: Short answer: I'm not starting with a clean slate.

I want to build a Cocoa UI for an existing C# application (as opposed to using GTK# or WinForms).

It's not worth duplicating my current code in Objective C, then maintaining two sets of equivalent code going forward.

Comment: But you can still use Objective-C for the UI and use one of the bridges listed in your question to reuse your existing model code. This is the approach recommended for cross-platform apps on OS X.

Comment: I've spent a little more than 2-3 days with Objective-C now, and while I find it cleaner than C++, it is still considerably lower level than C#.  As a Python programmer, even C# feels pretty low level and wordy.  You do gain a heck of a lot of productivity by going with a higher level language.  A well written C#-Objc bridge would ideally let you have most of your cake and eat it too.

Comment: Let's not even mention the all too real risks of CTS when having to code with a wordy low level language (yes, Xcode completion mitigates this to some extent)... and one can start to see why a higher level language than ObjC is an extremely desirable goal for Cocoa programmers.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly lengthy discussion of the various bridges has taken place on the Mono-OSX mailing list.

The discussion starts [here](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-osx/2009-May/002240.html) with Miguel:

- Announcing that Cocoa# will no longer be maintained by Novell.
- Attempting to unify the remaining efforts in the community.

If you read the rest of the discussion, it appears that the Mono community is leaning towards either Monoobjc or MObjc / MCocoa; so if you're doing your own investigations these are probably the ones to focus on.

Comment: I have added a new answer to this question focussing on MonoMac. 

I left this answer untouched in case the details are useful to people interested in how MonoMac came about.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to ask why, since you have your reasons I am sure.

I would look at the Unity3D project and see if you can suss out how they did it. Looks, um, hard.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I was interested in the bridges that already exist, as opposed to writing a new one...