# Monobjc and Mac UI for Windows Application

Tags: c#, objective-c, cocoa, user-interface, monobjc

I've got an application which was written in C# and is running on Windows and Linux using Mono. Now we need a native user interface for the Mac. Is there a way of doing this using Monobjc? Did anyone ever work with it? Is there any other approach?

Thanks for your help
–f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac) can help you achieve this. While I've only played with it briefly, it seems pretty stable but is a seperate download. This seems to be the preferered way to do this and is actively supported while Cocoa# is being fazed out

[Here's a link with more details about different approaches](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX)

[See this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719895/building-cocoa-uis-for-os-x-with-c-and-mono)

Answer (score 1):

we've used MonobjC for the exact same thing.

I'd highly recommend it.
There are others out there (cocoa#, ...) but this one seems to be the most complete.
It is very actively maintained, which lots of excellent support if you need it.
Check out the samples, fairly easy too.

The other option is indeed MonoMac.
It's the new, officially supported version, but, as far as I know, it's not exactly 100% finished yet. Expect some bugs/unimplemented stuff here + very small userbase currently.

For the moment, if you want everything to work, I'd still recommend Monobjc.